# IIS 8 - Stop remote

Tags: iis, iis-8

I recently got a new laptop.  I added IIS manager and connected to a remote website. i need to be able to stop the website from IIS. I used to be able to do this on my old laptop.

I  was able to connect but i have no option under actions to Stop, start, or restart the site. I dont know what is wrong and can't figure it out. Hope someone can help! thank you in advance

Comment: Ask your server administrators on how they configured remote administration for your account, and they are the only ones who can fix the issue for you. They should be quite familiar with guides like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7 and what settings they can change. There is nothing you or anyone here can help.

Comment: I would like to confirm with you, are you using the IIS-8? IIS-8 is not supported anymore. I tried to access remote site via IIS on my test VM and I found that there are no options to start, stop, restart site.  [See Here](https://imgur.com/a/poeCJrB).